# How to create universal iOS app on Xcode 6 with and without using storyboard?

Tags: iphone, ios8, xcode6

I worked on upgrading the app to iOS 8 and shifted Xcode 5 to Xcode 6 for iPhone 6 and 6 plus devices. The app work fine in iPhone 6 and 6 plus. But when creating new app in Xcode 6 same thing doesn't happen. I tried using constraints but that is not easy to handle things. I want to know is that the only way to work on Xcode 6 for making all devices compatible app because more complex design the more difficult to handle constraints. Is there any other way other than storyboard. Or any other smarter way to do this with some less complexity. Please guide.

Answer (score -2):

You can use a single iPhone storyboard and set this in your project for iPhone and iPad. I think there is no easier way.

If you have problems, please be more specific.